# Cannot resolve method maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using android studio and trying to bring in google maps. In my android manifest I have added these lines:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />/>
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
    android:value="myKEY" />
```

And when I try and create a map in my xml I get the error:

```
Cannot resolve method maps
```

My xml I created looks like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The cannot resolve method maps is on this line:

```
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

Code:

```
package com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.SearchView;

/**
 * Created by Mike on 3/17/14.
 */
public class BreweryMap extends Fragment {

    public BreweryMap(){}

    String beerId = "";
    SearchView searchView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_brewmap, container, false);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);






        return rootView;
    }






}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to this instead:

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```

and in the Fragment you can do this

```
public class MyFragment extends SupportMapFragment
```

this worked for me. Everything else seems to be correct. Maybe its your code but try to extend SupportMapFragment.

Comment: that did not fix my error in my xml and in my java code it says cannot resolve method SupportMapFragment

Comment: adding it right now. Its still kinda a shell, because I didn't want to add much to it until I fixed the error in the xml...

Comment: you are extending Fragment in your BreweryMap.class at this line: public class BreweryMap extends Fragment, but you should extend MapFragment.